# Generating points from chainage and offset

Tags: qgis, arcgis-10.0, point, mapinfo, routing

I have a polyline layer and an external csv containing road sign data. The csv has unique ID of the polyline, chainage along each unique segment and an offset. I have access to ArcGIS, MapInfo and QGIS, is there any way I can generate point data from this data?

Answer (score 1):

Using **[Linear Referencing](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003900000001000000)** of **ArcGIS for Desktop** the steps are:

1. **[Create Routes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Create_Routes/003m00000005000000/)** to create routes from your polylines
2. **[Make Route Event Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Make_Route_Event_Layer/003m00000008000000/)** to place your road signs as point events along the routes
3. **[Copy Features](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000035000000)** to copy point events to a point feature class